Proof that I can always swap $(\phi)$ and $(\neg\neg\phi)$ for each other in axiomatic propositional logic
I am working in propositional logic with alphabet $\{(,),\neg,\to,P_i\}$. The axioms I am using are

$\phi \to (\psi \to \phi)$
$((\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \chi)) \rightarrow ((\phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \chi)))$
$(((\neg \psi) \rightarrow (\neg \phi)) \rightarrow (((\neg \psi) \rightarrow \phi) \rightarrow \psi))$

and modus ponens. I have already proven the following theorems:

$\vdash \phi \to \neg\neg\phi$
$\vdash \neg\neg\phi \to \phi$

My question: How do I formally prove that from now on I can always substitute any instance of $\phi$ with $\neg\neg\phi$ in any line of a proof and vice versa? More specifically, it is obvious that from these theorem one can show that if $(\phi \to \psi)$, then $(\neg\neg\phi \to \psi)$. However, it is not equally simple to show that $(\phi \wedge \psi)$ is equivalent to $(\neg\neg\phi \wedge \psi)$ or that $\neg(\neg\phi \wedge \psi) \to \neg\chi$ can be converted to $\neg(\neg\phi \wedge \neg\neg\psi) \to \neg\chi$. Moreover, the two proofs differ and there are an infinite amount more of distinct formulas and substitution that differ in the way they would be shown to be equivalent to a double negation version. Is there a way to show all these at once?
My guess: I am trying to perform an induction on all formulas. That is show that one can always swap propositional variables for their double negation, show that if one can do so for $\phi$, then one can do so for $\neg\phi$. Lastly that if one can do so for $(\phi \to \psi)$, then one can obtain $(\neg\neg\phi \to \psi)$ as well as $(\phi \to \neg\neg\psi)$, $(\neg\neg\phi \to \neg\neg\psi)$ and vice versa. Would that be sufficient? The problem I see is that I need to prove something for all subformulas rather than all formulas and it feels like cheating to prove it this way.
Edit: Here is my new improved proof. I need to prove that $(\phi \leftrightarrow \neg\neg\phi) \Rightarrow (\psi \leftrightarrow \psi')$ where $\psi'$ is the result of substituting some occurrences of $\phi$ within $\psi$ for $\neg\neg\psi$ or vice versa. By definition $\psi$ is the last element of a construction sequence $\langle \sigma_1,...,\sigma_n \rangle$ where $\sigma_n \equiv \psi$ and each $\sigma_i$ is either a propositional variable, the negation of a previous element or the conditional of two previous elements. Assume inductively that for all $\sigma_i$ with $i < n$ one has that $\phi \leftrightarrow \neg\neg\phi \Rightarrow (\sigma_i \leftrightarrow \sigma_i')$. Then, there are three cases to consider:

$\sigma_n$ is a propositional variable. Then, $\sigma_n'$ is simply $\neg\neg P_i$. Thus, this follows from the theorem already proved.

$\sigma_n$ is the negation of some $\sigma_i$ with $i < n$. Assume that $\phi \leftrightarrow \neg\neg\phi$. Then, by inductive hypothesis $\sigma_i \leftrightarrow \sigma_i'$. Thus,


\begin{align*}
\{\sigma_n\} &\vdash \neg\sigma_i \\
&\vdash \sigma_i \leftrightarrow \sigma_i'\\
&\vdash \neg \sigma_i'\\
&\vdash \neg \sigma_n'
\end{align*}
Similarly for the other direction. Thus, $\sigma_n \leftrightarrow \sigma_n'$.

If $\psi \equiv \sigma_i \to \sigma_j$ a very similar reasoning holds.

By strong induction all elements of the sequence satisfy the required property. Thus, $\psi$ does as well. Since $\psi$ was chosen arbitrarily, the same holds for any formula. Would this work?

You have to prove $\leftrightarrow$ and you have to prove the Replacement (meta-)theorem.

@MauroALLEGRANZA what would be a statement of the replacement (meta)-theorem?

See e.g. here

The Answer below to use induction to directly prove the replacement theorem totally works.  Another route is a bit more indirect:  if you already know (or can prove) the soundness and completeness of your axioms, then you can simply point out that if your axioms can prove some $\phi$ that contains $\psi$ as a subformula, then that means (by soundness) that $\phi$ is a tautology, meaning that $\phi'$ (which is the result of replacing some instance of $\psi$ with $\neg \neg \psi$) is a tautology as well, meaning that (by completeness) your axioms can prove $\psi'$.

That said, the proof of soundness and completeness itself relies on very similar lemma's that the proof of the replacement theorem relies on. :P And yes, the key to all these meta-theorems is using induction on all formulas, you certainly had the right idea about that!

Your hunch to use induction is correct, but the way you try to apply induction is not.
The statement you want to prove (what Mauro Allegranza called the replacement meta-theorem in the comments) is "for all formula $φ$, for all formula $ψ$ which occurs at a subformula in $φ$, the formula $φ'$ obtained by replacing any instance of $ψ$ in $φ$ by $¬¬ψ$ satisfies $φ ⇔ φ'$.
The most natural proof is by induction on the "context" inside which $ψ$ appears in $φ$ (formally, a context is a formula with a "blank", often denoted by a square as in $¬((B ∨ □) ∧ A)$, which you can view as a special variable).

If there is no context ($φ = ψ$), we want to show $φ ⇔ ¬¬φ$, which you've already done.
If the context is $α ∧ β$ where the square is in $α$, denote by $α_1$ and $α_2$ the formulas respectively obtained by replacing the square with $ψ$ or $¬¬ψ$, then we have $α_1 ⇔ α_2$ by induction hypothesis, and we need to prove $α_1 ∧ β ⇔ α_2 ∧ β$ which I'll leave you as an exercise. Note that we are proving $(α_1 ⇔ α_2) ⇒ (α_1 ∧ β ⇔ α_2 ∧ β)$, not $α ∧ β ⇔ ¬¬α ∧ β$ (which would be true but doesn't help the induction as the double negation is added not on $α$ but inside $α$).
Likewise, we get to prove $(β_1 ⇔ β_2) ⇒ (α ∧ β_1 ⇔ α ∧ β_2)$, $(α_1 ⇔ α_2) ⇒ (α_1 ∨ β ⇔ α_2 ∨ β)$, $(β_1 ⇔ β_2) ⇒ (α ∨ β_1 ⇔ α ∨ β_2)$, $(α_1 ⇔ α_2) ⇒ ((α_1 ⇒ β) ⇔ (α_2 ⇒ β))$, $(β_1 ⇔ β_2) ⇒ ((α ⇒ β_1) ⇔ (α ⇒ β_2))$, which are all easy exercises.


Thanks for the answer. Induction on context appears similar to induction on complexity of the formula. How to the two differ? What is the explicit inductive step? What about negation? Does that have a context? It would follow for free from the theorem I have already proved right?

Could you also say more about why my attempt with induction is wrong? It seems that what they are doing here (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3875365/1059653) (accepted answer) is the same as what I was trying to do.

“What about negation?” → There are two essentially equivalent ways to work with negation in propositional logic, one is to define $¬φ$ as a notation for $φ ⇒ ⊥$, and the other is to have $¬$ as a logical symbol like $∨, ∨, ⇒$. If you use the first one, you don't need to do anything for negation in the induction ($(φ ⇔ φ') ⇒ (¬φ ⇔ ¬φ')$ is a special case of $(α_1 ⇔ α_2) ⇒ ((α_1 ⇒ β) ⇔ (α_2 ⇒ β))$ with $β = ⊥$). Otherwise you also need to prove $(φ ⇔ φ') ⇒ (¬φ ⇔ ¬φ')$, which is just as easy as the others.

Why your attempt with induction is wrong → As far as I understand your original question, you were proving things like $(¬¬φ ∧ ψ) ⇔ (φ ∧ ψ)$ and $(¬¬φ ⇒ ψ) ⇔ (φ ⇒ ψ)$ in the induction step, but that is not what the induction requires. If the statement to be proven by induction is “you can replace a formula with its double negation anywhere in another formula”, then when your formula is e.g. $φ ∧ ψ$, the replacement could be anywhere inside $φ$ or $ψ$. But you're assuming the replacement is "shallow", that it happens on $φ$ or $ψ$ itself.

For example, specialize your proof to the formula $(a ∧ ¬¬b) ∨ c$ where we want to replace $¬¬b$ by $b$. One application of the induction step proves $a ∧ ¬¬b ⇔ a ∧ b$. But now the second induction step should prove $(a ∧ ¬¬b) ∨ c$ from the induction hypothesis $a ∧¬¬b ⇔a ∧ b$. The $¬¬$ is inside $a ∧ ¬¬b$, so this does not follow from what you did in your induction step, $¬¬φ ∨ ψ ⇔ φ ∨ ψ$. Instead the correct way to derive it is to prove $(φ ⇔ φ') ⇒ (φ ∨ ψ ⇔ φ' ∨ ψ)$, where $φ = a ∧ ¬¬b, φ' = a ∧ b, ψ = c$ in this particular case.

What's the difference between induction on the formula and induction on the context? → With induction on the context, the base case is when there is no context ($φ = □$). You don't “descend into the context”. With induction on the formula, the base case is a variable.

I added my new and modified proved. Do you think it would work now?

It looks "more" correct, it's weird though to say "we want to prove that $φ ⇔ ¬¬φ$ implies something" because $φ ⇔ ¬¬φ$ is always true, so this is redundant. (There are also some typos.) And you also need to handle the case where $φ$ is not a propositional variable. But even though you can "flatten" the structural induction to an induction on natural numbers, a structural induction is usually simpler and more readable.

Thanks. I agree, the premise is redundant. However, I do not understand your "case where $\phi$ is not a propositional variable". What case is this? $\phi$ has to be a prop variable or the negation of a formula or the conditional of two formulas, there are no other options.
